# How do I forward from one domain to another?

Tags: proxy, apache-2.2

I'm trying to set up the AJAX Push Engine, and I've run into some complications using apache. All I want to do, is whenever I go to some address (e.g. `*.example.com`), forward it to some other address (e.g. `mysite.com`).

My `httpd-vhosts.conf` looks like this...

```
NameVirtualhost *.example.com

<VirtualHost *.example.com>
    ServerName example.com
    ProxyPass / http://mysite.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

But if I ping `0.example.com`, it doesn't give me the IP address of `mysite.com`.

What is it that I am missing? If there is an easier way to do this without apache, I'm all ears: I had previously tried to just edit the hosts file, but apparently host files can't contain wildcards.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I ping 0.example.com, it doesn't
>   give me the IP address of mysite.com.

The IP address you get for 0.example.com is returned by a DNS server. If you can edit the DNS record for example.com, then you can get that domain name to resolve to the IP of your choice.

If you just need to do some local testing, then you can edit your hosts file, so your machine will resolve any hostname to any IP you like, but doing that only affects your own machine.